# Random image generator project (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

While completing a project for FreeCodeCamp I had the idea to create a simple website which can get me a random picture of a cat when pressing a button. So I found the http://thecatapi.com/ which will get me a random src so I can add it to my img tag. I've made this with jQuery as it's easier from me coming from FCC.

As the api will get me the random source url I didn't think it would be difficult, however with the code I implemented, the button which request for a cat only works the first time it's clicked.

Here is my HTML

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="" id="kitties">
<div class="catText"> <h1>Your cat will spawn here!</h1></div>

<div class="buttons text-center">
   <a class="btn btn-info" target="_blank" id="tweetButton">Tweet it!</a>
   <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="kittyButton"> Generate </button>
</div>
```

And my Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#kittyButton").on("click", function(){
      $('.catText').remove();
      $("#kitties").attr('src','http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get')
   });
});
```

How can I get a different image each time I click on the button?

Thanks in advance, you can see the whole code in my codepen right [HERE](https://codepen.io/johanjozz/pen/NMyzOj?editors=1010)

Comment: Because the URL doesn't change, the browser caches the result. A simple hack is to change the URL like this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/p17t6bvr/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vrNYey?editors=1010

Updated your code to add random number at the end of string as to avoid `browser caching` , refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching

```
 var rnd = new Date().getTime();
```

The above code will get EPOC time and the request will be unique every time

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kittyButton").on("click", function(){
   $('.catText').remove();
 var rnd = new Date().getTime();

$("#kitties").attr('src','http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=jpg,png?'+rnd)
// $('#tweetButton').attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' +('"'+HOAAAAAAAA+'"'+"  - "+GATITAAAAAAA));
      }); 
});
```

Comment: Wow! thank you, I'll definitely read about caching. Have a nice day!